# How I can I convert timezones in Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, gmt

I am trying to convert a date/time GMT 0 to GMT -6 in Perl.

For example, a DHCP Server lease time is in the following format:

> 2010/02/18 23:48:37

I am trying to convert that time to the Localtime zone (GMT -6) but need it to honor Daylight savings time.

The script below may be overkill, but I am not sure how to proceed from here.  (Any suggestions would be awsome).

```
my $TIMESTART;

$TIMESTART = "2010/02/18 23:48:37";
$TIMESTART =~ s/\//-/g;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

use DateTime::Format::MySQL;
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime($TIMESTART);

my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Chicago' );

print $tz->offset_for_datetime($dt) . "\n";
```

It will output the following lines:

> 2010-02-18T23:48:37
>   -21600

I need to be able to add -21600 to the date to get the local time zone of GMT -6 but I am not sure how to approch this.

Comment: Other than use within the UK, please use UTC, rather than GMT as the international standard time. Some systems assume GMT means UTC, while others assume GMT/BST, as used in UK.

Comment: I guess there's more than one way to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call [`set_time_zone`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.53/lib/DateTime.pm#"Set"_Methods) method 2 times:

```
my $dt = DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime($TIMESTART);
$dt->set_time_zone('UTC'); ## set timezone of parsed date time
$dt->set_time_zone('America/Chicago'); ## change timezone in safe way

print DateTime::Format::MySQL->format_datetime($dt),"\n"; ## check the result
```

How it works:

- when you create `DateTime` object without time zone specified, "floating" time zone is set
- first call of `set_time_zone` change time zone to `UTC` without conversion
- second call of `set_time_zone` change `UTC` to `America/Chicago`

Comment: Running it the second time was the piece I was missing.  It works, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I too had not realized the second call to set_time_zone() was the key.

Comment: I haven't tried the above method of creating a DateTime object, but if you create one using `now()`, or create one from a timestamp, it will have the time zone UTC.  `DateTime->now()` for now, or `DateTime->from_epoch(1582040334)` to use a timestamp. If you then get the `time_zone_long_name()`, it will be UTC. (Note: I am doing this in 2020, and your answer is from 2010.)

Answer (score 1):

This will convert UTC time into ETC time.
You can also use date/time in any format using +FORMAT parameter of date.

date --date='TZ="ETC" 18:30'

Answer (score 0):

[`Time::Piece`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Piece) is a very lightweight piece of code of good quality. Or you can just use built-ins and [`strftime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX) and [`POSIX::strptime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX::strptime)

Comment: Time::Piece is for displaying of dates, not date math. All it will get you the hour offset,  and I'm not even sure that number is daylight-savings safe. There are no functions for date math.

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't Use Timezones With `DateTime::Format::MySQL->parse_datetime`

There is a very good reason you shouldn't be using this when doing anything relating to timezones.  Why?  Because it has absolutely no support for timezones whatsoever.  Please see the documentation:

> All of the parsing methods set the returned DateTime object's time zone ***to the floating time zone***, because MySQL ***does not provide time zone information.*** (Source: [**MetaCPAN: DateTime::Format::MySQL**](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::MySQL).)

If you DO use this, it will assume your system time zone default.  This *might not be* the timezone you want to convert from!  (Although this will work for many people, it only works as long as your servers don't change their default timezone — after that, everything breaks.)

#### Use `DateTime->new()`, Because It DOES Support TimeZones

Use the constructor that `DateTime` provides directly (Source: [**MetaCPAN: DateTime**](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#DateTime-%3Enew(-...-)).):

```
my $dt = DateTime->new(
    year       => 1966,
    month      => 10,
    day        => 25,
    hour       => 7,
    minute     => 15,
    second     => 47,
    nanosecond => 500000000,
    time_zone  => 'America/Chicago',
);
```

#### Convert TimeZones with DateTime

Your *starting time zone* is whatever you feed into the constructor (i.e., `America/Chicago` in the above example).  To convert a time to an ending time zone, use `set_time_zone()`.

#### Working Code

In the code below, a time is converted from one timezone to another, and it does this perfectly every time, even you are converting New York time to San Francisco time with a server whose Linux OS is in Singapore time.

```
use strict;
use DateTime;

sub convertTimeZonesForTime {
        my ($args) = @_;

        my $time = $args->{time};
        my $date = $args->{date};
        my $totimezone = $args->{totimezone};
        my $fromtimezone = $args->{fromtimezone};
        my $format = $args->{format} || '%H:%M:%S';

        my ($year, $month, $day) = map {int $_} split('-', $date);
        my ($hour, $minute, $second) = map {int $_} split(':', $time);

        $year ||= 1999 if !defined $year;
        $month ||= 1 if !defined $month;
        $day ||= 1 if !defined $day;
        $hour ||= 12 if !defined $hour;
        $minute ||= 30 if !defined $minute;
        $second ||= 0 if !defined $second;

        my $dt = DateTime->new(
                year=>$year,
                month=>$month,
                day=>$day,
                hour=>$hour,
                minute=>$minute,
                second=>$second,
                time_zone => $fromtimezone,
        );
        my $formatter = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(pattern => $format);
        $dt->set_formatter($formatter);
        $dt->set_time_zone($totimezone);

        return "$dt";
}

print(convertTimeZonesForTime({
    'totimezone'=>'America/Denver',
    'fromtimezone'=>'US/Eastern',
    'time'=>'12:30:00',
}));
```

Output:

> 10:30:00

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) = gmtime(time+21600);
$year = $year + 1900;
printf("%02d:%02d:%02d %02d.%02d.%04d\n", $hour,$min,$sec,$mday,$mon,$year);
```

Comment: This is flat out wrong at times, as it ignores the part of the question that says "but need it to honor Daylight savings time".